# negative effects of infinite recursion in python3?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

What negative effects should I be concerned about with a indefinitely long running script that is infinitely recursive?

My script looks something like this:

```
class foo():
    def __init__(self):
        some_instance_vars = 42
        self.a()

    def a(self):
        manipulate(self.some_instance_vars)
        do_io()
        self.b()

    def b(self):
        manipulate_again(self.some_instance_vars)
        do_io()
        self.c()

    def c(self):
        manipulate_more(self.some_instance_vars)
        do_io()
        self.a()

foo = Foo()
```

Some things I can imagine:

1. This would break the garbage collection because the previous calls are always in scope.
2. Python puts something in memory for each loop and it infinitely builds up and eventually creates a memory problem.

Are these things problems? Are there other problems I haven't thought of?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: Python adds a new frame for each recursion even though its in tail position. It's done to show you a nice stack trace when you eventually get a stack overflow.  It's by design and you should use something else than recursion for your endless loop.